# Rename Table Name rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have table name like this **"custom.students"** in rails
Now I would like to change it as **"custom.class_one_students"**

I have tried multiple ways but nothing works like migration, sql and single quotation!

Comment: `rename_table('custom.students', 'custom.class_one_students')` should do it.  Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Note that the name `class_one_students` implies a poor table design; it's a table of students specific to a single class. Instead there should be students, classes, and a join table.

Comment: @Schwern,
I tried below things
  rename_table 'custom.students', 'custom.class_one_students'
  
 execute("ALTER TABLE custom.students RENAME TO custom.class_one_students")

Comment: I am facing this kind of issue while using your suggested code above
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."

Comment: What database are you using? From `PG::SyntaxError` I assumed PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have gone through this [documentation](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SET/SETSEARCH_PATH.htm?TocPath=SQL%20Reference%20Manual%7CSQL%20Statements%7CSET%20Statements%7C_____6) and it seems like for the custom schema, it would be effective to use `search_path` for alteration in database.it works for me!!

```
  class ChangeStudentTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
       def up
        execute(<<-SQL)
          SET search_path TO custom;
          ALTER TABLE custom.students RENAME TO custom.class_one_students;
          SET search_path TO "$user", public;
        SQL
      end
    end
```

Comment: This does not work in PostgreSQL. `alter table ... rename to ...` does not take a schema for the new name, only a table. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c33f95bde9088623969935c016d6a648).

Comment: I am using SQL query to run that statement and it is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

`alter table <name> rename to <new name>` takes a fully qualified table name, but the new name is just the table.

```
ALTER TABLE custom.students RENAME TO class_one_students;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca2d185a8f1c24f8de466a98f7339468).

You'd do this in a migration with `rename_table`. Again, only pass the table name as the new name.

```
rename_table('custom.students', 'class_one_students')
```

Note that the new name implies this is a table of students for a single class and that there will be a `class_two_students`, `class_three_students`, etc. This should instead be handled with `students`, `classes` and a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: I have customised schema..
if I am trying like this than it is throwing syntax error, I already tried that

Comment: @Foram Note that lack of a schema in the second part. Just use the table name. This is equivalent to `alter table custom.students rename to class_one_students`. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca2d185a8f1c24f8de466a98f7339468).